# Why output of ` struct T{ double x};` different in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, struct, language-lawyer

```
struct T{ double x};
```

In C, it creates no problem.

But in C++, it gives the following compilation error:

> expected ';' at end of member declaration.

Comment: because they are different languages?

Comment: I like quirky things like this. I wonder what's different in the grammars. I've tagged "language-lawyer".

Comment: My VC 2008 (C compilation) says: "error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'"

Comment: n C++ this is an error, but C is not happy with that either, it should generate a warning.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie you got `-Werror -Wall` there?

Comment: This likely dependent on your compiler and compilation commands. Please [edit] and add that information.

Comment: Sourav, `/W3` of VC, and it says "syntax _error_. I don;t believe errors can be suppressed so VC considers this an error in the grammatical use of the language.

Answer (score 12):

From C11, "Structure and union specifiers, syntax" (6.7.2.1/1):

*struct-declaration*:
    *specifier-qualifier-list*  *struct-declarator-list*<sub>opt</sub> `;`

Each element of a struct ends in a semicolon. Your claim that there is "no problem" is not based on what the C specification says. If your compiler accepts such code, it is not a conforming C compiler, or you are not using it correctly. (Some compilers have a configurable level of standards conformance.)

Comment: Right sir, but if you can add some info on why compiler does not generate an error, that would be good. OP seems to expect that this should be syntax error but compiler does not generate any. Why's that?

Comment: Basically I'm asking, why the compiler thinks "no problem"?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I don't know what cheap compiler you've picked up - how am I supposed to answer that? Use a standard C compiler.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: "Please explain in detail the possible outcome of an operation not constrained by any specification or convention."

Comment: I used gcc 4.9.2, sad to hear it's _cheap_, my whole life is a lie.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Well, either your compiler sucks, or your understanding of how to drive it does ... :-S GCC may be cheap, but it is definitely not easy to use correctly for the novice...

Comment: OK, sorry for annoying, but just to clarify, isn't this supposed to be a syntax error?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Yes, indeed, that's what this answer is saying. Anything not allowed by the standard requires a "compiler error", unless the standard explicitly says that no diagnostic is required (e.g. for ODR violations).

Comment: Ahh, I missed the previous sarcasm. :) I was not looking for detailed explanation, was kind of expecting some sort of compiler extension which allows this (like 0-sized array) for some reason, but thanks anyway.

Comment: By the way, GCC 4.9.2 here gives *warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union*.

Comment: The compiler would be conforming so long as a diagnostic is issued (OP is unclear whether or not one is)

Comment: @M.M: Yes, that's why I put "compiler error" in quotes. There's no "error" in the Standard, nor is there a "compiler".

Answer (score 3):

The GCC parser for C grammar is implemented [as follows](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.c#L2967):

```
  /* If no semicolon follows, either we have a parse error or
     are at the end of the struct or union and should
     pedwarn.  */
  if (c_parser_next_token_is (parser, CPP_SEMICOLON))
    c_parser_consume_token (parser);
  else
    {
      if (c_parser_next_token_is (parser, CPP_CLOSE_BRACE))
    pedwarn (c_parser_peek_token (parser)->location, 0,
         "no semicolon at end of struct or union");
      else if (parser->error
           || !c_parser_next_token_starts_declspecs (parser))
    {
      c_parser_error (parser, "expected %<;%>");
      c_parser_skip_until_found (parser, CPP_CLOSE_BRACE, NULL);
      break;
    }

      /* If we come here, we have already emitted an error
     for an expected `;', identifier or `(', and we also
         recovered already.  Go on with the next field. */
    }
```

It calls function `pedwarn` on a missing semicolon.

The definition of `pedwarn` can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DiagnosticsGuidelines). It reads:

> - `pedwarn` is for **code that is accepted by GCC but it should be rejected or diagnosed according to the current standard**, or it conflicts with the standard (either the default or the one selected by `-std=`). It can also diagnose compile-time undefined behavior (but not runtime UB). `pedwarns` become errors with `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why output of `struct T{ double x};` different in C and C++?

The example struct definition is ill-formed in both C and C++.

C and C++ are different languages, they use different parsers (or whatever component of the compiler detects this error). The output is different because different decisions were made by people when they implemented the parser of the C compiler, than were made when the C++ parser  was implemented.

Latter decided to issue an error, the former issues merely a warning, and successfully compiles despite the bug. Another C compiler can refuse to compile as well, and a C++ compiler can accept the program (as long as it produces a warning).

Comment: I find this a very poor explanation. It is not about decissions, it is about perscriptions (by the standard of the language).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie there is no difference in the *perscriptions* in this case. Neither language allows leaving out the semicolon in this context. Both languages require a diagnostic message when the program is ill-formed. Both languages allow the the compiler to produce a program anyway (extending the language is allowed). The implementer of the compiler gets to **decide** whether to extend the language and allow compilation, or not.

Answer (score -3):

Generally, **C** language likes semicolon much more than **Pascal** (**Delphi**). In your case, **C** accepts `struct T{ double x};`, but **C++** already requires `struct T{ double x;};`

Comment: The semicolon is formally (in C) a statement _terminator_. It signals the end of a statement (or turns e.g. an expression into a statement). Other languages use statement _separators_ so if no statement follows, the separator can (or should) be omitted. In C they cannot be omitted. There are cases where the omission is still unambiguous, cases where a compiler may flag this error as a warning.

Comment: Paul Ogilvie, thanks, I meant the same, you've said it better then me. Indeed, Pascal requires semicolon as separator, not terminator. But the question was: why does **C** allow to omit semicolon in structure field?

Comment: It does not. The compiler should have generated an error in stead of a warning. The code is now not portable anymore (unless these warnings have been solved too).